# How to make a variable set in controller, available in other class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

In my controller I have:

```
  def index
    @grid = UsersGrid.new(params[:users_grid]) do |scope|
      scope.where(admin: false).page(params[:page]).per_page(30)
    end
    @grid.assets
    if (current_user && current_users.admin?)
      @show_column = true
    else
      @show_column = false
    end
  end
```

In my grid class:

```
class UsersGrid

  include Datagrid
  scope do
    User.order("users.created_at desc")
  end

  column(:abc, :header => "abc?", :html => true, :if => proc {@show_column == true}) do |user|
    image_tag("abc.png", title: "abc") if user.abc
  end
end
```

So in the controller I set `@show_column`, and in the class it should show the column `:abc` depending on whether `@show_column` is true or false. This goes wrong as `@show_column` is an instance variable and not available in the grid class. So it's nil. How should I change this to make this work?

Comment: @show_column must be the parameter to the Grid class

Comment: You can try this by using session
e.g. in controller  `session[:show_column] = true` instead of @show_column = true and in model `:if => proc {session[:show_column] == true}` instead of :if => proc {@show_column == true}

Comment: You shouldn't evolve questions like this. It invalidates existing answers. Ask another question instead.

Comment: Thanks Sergio, I've rolled back the post to the original question and will ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass down the variable when creating the `UsersGrid` instance, then save it in an instance variable there.

In controller:

```
def index
  @show_column = (current_user && current_users.admin?)
  @grid = UsersGrid.new(params[:users_grid], @show_column) do |scope|
    scope.where(admin: false).page(params[:page]).per_page(30)
  end
  @grid.assets
end
```

In the grid class:

```
class UsersGrid
  def initialize(*params, show_column)
    super *params
    @show_column = show_column
  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: I initally thought this worked but it didn't. `@show_column` is still nil in the grid class (I know this because it only shows the column if I use `proc {@show_column == nil}`.

Comment: I also tried it with `@show_column = true` in the controller. But then still `@show_column` is nil in the class and it shows the column only it I use `proc {@show_column == nil}`. So it doesn't seem to correctly pass on the `@show_column` value to the grid class.

Comment: @Nick : Add `attr_reader :show_column` in your `UsersGrid` class and then use it so: `proc {show_column == true}`. It should work.

Comment: Thanks, this gave the error message `undefined local variable or method `show_column' for UsersGrid:Class` referring to the line `proc {show_column == true}`. Changing this to `@show_column` removed the error message but got me back to original problem that the column only shows if I change that to `proc {show_column == nil}`.

Comment: Also noticeable is that adding the `debugger` *inside*  `def initialize` shows `@show_column` as true, while *outside* `def initialize` it says `nil` for `@show_column` and it says `NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method 'show_column'` for `show_column`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **attr_accessor** for a variable that is not a column of a table.

```
def index
    params[:users_grid][:show_column] = (current_user && current_users.admin?)
    @grid = UsersGrid.new(params[:users_grid]) do |scope|
      scope.where(admin: false).page(params[:page]).per_page(30)
    end
    @grid.assets    
  end

class UsersGrid

  include Datagrid
  scope do
    User.order("users.created_at desc")
  end
attr_accessor :show_column

  column(:abc, :header => "abc?", :html => true, :if => proc {self.show_column == true}) do |user|
    image_tag("abc.png", title: "abc") if user.abc
  end
end
```

Comment: This gave an error message `undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass` referring to the line `params[:users_grid][:show_column] = (current_user && current_users.admin?)`

Comment: is params[:users_grid] nil?

Comment: I think so, `undefined method '[]=' for nil:NilClass` I think refers to `[:show_column]`. I'm pretty sure it doesn't refer to `(current_user && current_users.admin?)` since these are used in other views as well and function properly there.

Comment: try to do binding.pry and check for params[:users_grid] and then check for current_user && current_users.admin? condition and let me know

Comment: I've tried using byebug debugger. If I place `debugger` before the `params` line, I can confirm that `current_user.admin?` is `true`. If I place the `debugger` after the `params` line, the debugger doesn't run because the original error message gets produced.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78893/discussion-between-user123-and-nick).